# Nagios trap snmptt fails to trigger

Tags: nagios, snmp

I want to monitor a HP 7500 switch power supplies. I have my OID, given by the HP web interface. So I create a snmptt.conf.hp, I create a service, passive and volatile, add this OID to a trap, and linked trap to service, then service to host.

I configured snmptt.conf, in order to log as `/var/log/snmptt.log`, and `snmptt_unknown.log`. With `log_enable = 1`, and `debugging = 1` ... But nothing happens! No log at all! No `smptt*.log` or `snmptrapd.log` ...

By looking with tcpdump, I'm sure that traps arrive well. But Nagios.log tell me this:

```
Warning: The results of service 'Service_Trap_PowerSupply_KO' on host 'XX.XX.XX.XX' are stale by 0d 0h 0m 59s (threshold=0d 0h 5m 0s).  I'm forcing an immediate check of the service.
Warning: The results of service 'Service_Trap_PowerSupply_OK' on host 'XX.XX.XX.XX' are stale by 0d 0h 0m 59s (threshold=0d 0h 5m 0s).  I'm forcing an immediate check of the service.
```

So name of my services look ok. On trap for KO the other for OK. When we unplug on powersupply, this is recorded in `nagios.log`.